# Umbraco Razor Syntax Issue

Tags: razor, umbraco

I have this macro running happily on a live server. It was ok in WebMatrix. Now WebMatrix has updated itself to 2 (refresh), it won't run some macros, this being one of them:-

```
    @{
  //Check there are slider image page loaded
  var theCount = @Model.Descendants("SliderImagePage").Count();

  if (theCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (var theImagePage in Model.Descendants("SliderImagePage"))
          {
           var theImage = theImagePage.Media("sliderImage","umbracoFile");
           if (theImagePage.IsFirst()) 
           {
            @:<div class="slide" style="background-image:url('@Html.Raw(theImage)');display:block;"></div>
            } else {
            @:<div class="slide" style="background-image:url('@Html.Raw(theImage)');display:none;"></div>
            }
          }    
     }
  else
  {
   @: No Picture Image pages set up
  }

}
```

It complains that ":" is not valid at the start of a code block.

I have MVC4 and the Razor Extensions in VS2010.  As far as I understand, it's all valid. Can anyone shed any light on why it won't pass validation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements in the foreach loop should run fine without using @: for output:

```
@{
    //Check there are slider image page loaded
    var theCount = @Model.Descendants("SliderImagePage").Count();

    if (theCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (var theImagePage in Model.Descendants("SliderImagePage"))
        {
            var theImage = theImagePage.Media("sliderImage","umbracoFile");
            if (theImagePage.IsFirst()) 
            {
                <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('@Html.Raw(theImage)');display:block;"></div>
            }
            else 
            {
                <div class="slide" style="background-image:url('@Html.Raw(theImage)');display:none;"></div>
            }
        }    
     }
    else
    {
        @: No Picture Image pages set up
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, removed them but VS2010 still complained about the @: No Picture Image line so put it in @Html.Raw("Here"); and it seems to have passed muster.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've discovered a compilation issue in Razor.  There is a simple workaround; if you remove the '@' character from line 3, the code you gave above compiles in both Razor v1 and Razor v2.

I have opened a bug in the Web pages team's bug database on CodePlex for this, and hopefully it will be addressed in the next version.

HTH,
Clay

Comment: Thank you Clay. Your workaround had allowed me to modify all my macros and get them working except one which appears to be due to html start and end tags being out of scope but I don't know how else to do it:
<ul@Html.Raw(ulClass)>
@foreach(){
code here
}
</ul>
Can't put full code here as it's too long.

Comment: Hi Craig, for that, what if you use: <ul class="@ulClass"> @foreach() { code } </ul>
-- Gareth / agrath